# How do I prevent multiple logins on the same account in play framework?

Tags: java, session, playframework

I have a system built using Play Framework 2.3.4, and Ebean for persistence. I want to ensure that if a user that is already authenticated in one session logs in again, his other session becomes invalid.

This would make it harder for two people to share the same account.

Is there a common pattern used for this type of feature in Play?

Comment: What are you using for an authentication system?

Comment: I'm using play.mvc.Security. My implementation just stores the logged in users email in the session. I'm currently working on an solution for this where I store an session id on the user and in the session also.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a solution to this where I persist an integer property with the user called `sessionCounter`. This is incremented each time the user authenticates (as in provides username password) and stored both in the user record and the new session.

Each time an existing session is used to access the system it is compared with the session counter and if the session has a lower value than the one in the DB that session is invalidated.

Here is the authenticate methood:

```
/**
 * Handle login form submission.
 */
public static Result authenticate() {
    Form<Login> loginForm = form(Login.class).bindFromRequest();
    if(loginForm.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(login.render(loginForm));
    } else {
        User user = loginForm.get().user;
        session().clear();
        session("username", user.getEmail());
        session("counter", ""+user.incrementSessionCounter());
        user.setLastLoginDate(new Date());
        user.save();
```

Here is the `play.mvc.Security.Authenticator` implementation:

```
@Override
public String getUsername(Http.Context context) {
    final User user;
    if ( !context.args.containsKey("user") ) {
        user = ExtranetUser.findByEmail(context.session().get("username"));
        context.args.put("user", user);
    } else {
        user = (User) context.args.get("user");
    }
    if(user != null){
        final String counterStr = context.session().get("counter");
        if (user.getSessionCounter() > NumberUtils.toInt(counterStr, 0)) {
            Logger.debug("Session invalidated for " + user + " had session " + counterStr + " but latest session is " + user.getSessionCounter());
            context.flash().put("session", "user.duplicateSession");
            context.session().clear();
            return null; // results in redirect to login page with flash
        }
        return user.getEmail();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would have the same approach but with unique token

Comment: I picked the integer because there is no need for the uniqueness because the PLAY_SESSION cookie ensures you cannot spoof it. It also counts the number of logins (which is vaguely useful).